# TYPO3 Solr: Use PidInRootLine as argument for a plugin.tx_solr.index.queue

Tags: solr, typo3

Is it possible create an EXT-Solr index queue with pages inside PidInRootLine or Slide?

something like:

```
pages {
  initialization = ApacheSolrForTypo3\Solr\IndexQueue\Initializer\Page

  // all the regular stuff here
  ...


  // only children or grant children of page 8
  pidInRootline = 8

  fields {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EXT-Solr does respect Page properties -> Behaviour -> Include in Search - Disable checkbox, so you can set on all the other pages this value. Just keep in mind that this checkbox might be also used for your SEO extension, but I assume it is OK, since you want to internally search only part of the tree.